# How to list target specific attributes in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

`llvm-objdump` has the option `-mattr`. If I do `llvm-objdump -help` the only useful information that I get is:

`-mattr=<a1,+a2,-a3,...>                   - Target specific attributes`

How can I list what are the "target specific attributes"?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a way to list the target specific attributes from `llvm-objdump`, but you can do this with the `llc` or `llvm-mc` with the args `-march=<your architecture> -mattr=help` (e.g. `llc -march=x86 -mattr=help`).